# Java: Loop not working

Tags: java, loops

Every time I try and run this code `currentCost` returns as `0`.

I am trying to calculate depreciation @ 20% using loops with the value and age of the asset (here a car) from the user. Thank you.

```
float cost = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
int vehicalAge = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
float currentCost = 0;
for (int a = 1; a == vehicalAge; a++) {
    cost = (float) (cost - (cost * 0.2));
    currentCost = cost;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, Float.toString(currentCost));
```

Comment: `a==vehicalAge` should be `a<=vehicalAge`

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in your for loop:

```
for (int a=1; a==vehicalAge;a++)
```

it should be

```
for (int a=1; a<=vehicalAge;a++)
```